# How do you avoid interrupting running Celery tasks when redeploying?

Tags: celery

I have an application which has celery workers as part of it. When I deploy this will kill those running processes.

So the tasks will have started, but won't ever finish, and won't be restarted when the deployment finished.

What's the best way to avoid this issue and have those tasks restart when the deployment finishes?

Is it to use acks_late on all my tasks? Or another way?

```
@celery.task(acks_late=True)
def my_task():
    pass
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please clarify, why do you have to kill celery worker processes instead of sending a TERM signal? Are your tasks long-running?

Comment: @Greenev If I'm using AWS beanstalk for example, I don't control how the processes end, AWS does. The tasks are very long running, multiple hours.

Comment: In this case you may want to override the application default `task_acks_late` setting

Answer (score 3):

What we do as part of the deployment process is to send the shutdown signal to all Celery workers in the cluster when we are about to deploy new code. Once the signal has been sent we begin the deployment and once the deployment finishes successfully we have a new set of workers subscribed to a predefined set of queues.

Worker processes that were created by the old Celery workers may continue running for next few hours (even days!), but they will not run any newly scheduled tasks as the moment they got the shutdown signal they unsubscribed from all queues.

As you can see, this process does not involve revoking and re-scheduling of tasks as that would be a much more complicated process as we sometimes have few thousands tasks running concurrently on hundreds of Celery nodes...

Comment: Do you have any worries about old workers breaking in case the db schema changed in a significant way? E.g. some column was renamed or no longer exists?

Comment: Also if you make 3 deploys in a few days is it possible to have 3 layers of old workers?

Comment: Yes, but old ones are not taking any new tasks, they are just running some old task(s) before they shutdown...

Comment: What if old workers are trying to access a column that was renamed or deleted after deployment? Old workers are running on old source that expects the old db schema, right?